# 6D pose estimation of a known 3D CAD object

Tags: computer-vision, pose, precise-positioning, reference-request

I'm looking for a codebase for 6DOF pose estimation of a known 3D CAD object with RGB or RGBD. It must be:

-Usable commercially (licensed under BSD, MIT, BOOST, etc.), not GPL.

-Easy to setup and use (having a running colab example would be great)

-The training time required for a new CAD object should be on the order of hours, not days.

-State of the art of near state of the art results. (See https://bop.felk.cvut.cz/home/ for benchmarks)

Are there any libraries fitting these requirements?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a shopping question.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Rexcirus, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Comment: Reddit is a better fit for these kind of questions indeed, you can find a good answer here: https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/v67xqh/6d_pose_estimation_of_a_known_3d_cad_object_2022_d/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to know about this too.
Vuforia combines libraries for several platforms (Android, iOS) and provides pose estimation. It uses 2D feature extracted from CAD and the feature extraction is fairly quick (minutes, not hours), but it is not CAD based pose estimation and the results are average (drift, stability, accuracy).
I came across this:
http://track.virnect.com/1.2.1/
Not tested

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as the most helpful, since the question has been closed.